# unable to return model object from controller to ajax method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Method in Controller :

```
public JsonResult FillStateDetails(string id)
        {
            var st1 = dbObj.States.Find(id);
            return Json(st1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Ajax call :

```
 $(document).ready(
            function () {
                $("#ddl1").change(
                    function () {
                        debugger
                        var ddlvl = $("#ddl1").val()
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: '@Url.Action("FillStateDetails", "Admin")',
                            data :{id : ddlvl},
                            dataType: "JSON",
                            contentType: "application/json",
                            success: function(date) {
                                alert(date);
                            },
                            error: function()
                            {
                                alert("Error");
                            }
                        });
                    });
            });
```

output:

unable to return the object from controller to Ajax method. error method is executing, how to return model object to ajax method.

Comment: Use you browser tools (the Network tab) to inspect the response - it will include the full details of the error message (we cannot debug you code for you)

Comment: And you also need to remove the `contentType: "application/json",` option in your ajax (you are not stringifying your data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use xhr,status,Text parameter in your error function of ajax request.You will get exact error.If you have Parser error then remove contentType tag from ajax call.